# how to display json and parse json in ruby using httparty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, parsing, httparty

I am working on a food app in ruby on rails  which requires to get calorie value of food item from food api.In my controller i am getting the JSON response but i am unable to parse and display the calorie value of food item in a index.html.erb file here is my controller code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class FoodsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @foods = Food.all
  end

  def show
    @food = Food.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @food = Food.new
  end

  def edit
   @food = Food.find(params[:id])
 end

 def create
   @food = Food.new(food_params)

   @response = HTTParty.get('http://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/'+@food.name+'?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_serving_size_unit%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=696d1ad4&appKey=aec2c4766d40d7f6346ed89d5d82fe75')
   @http_party_json = JSON.parse(@response.body)

  if @food.save
   redirect_to foods_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end


def update
  @food = Food.find(params[:id])

  if @food.update(food_params)
   redirect_to @food
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @food = Food.find(params[:id])
  @food.destroy

  redirect_to foods_path
end

private
def food_params
  params.require(:food).permit(:name, :quantity)
end

end
```

Any suggestions are highly welcome as i am newbie on stackoverflow so dont know proper editing forgive please! help me how to display calorie value in html page

Comment: which action you want to view data in ? index

Comment: @mohamed-ibrahim thanks for editing.i want to extract the calorie value of food item for example milk in this url https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/Milk?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_serving_size_unit%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=696d1ad4&appKey=aec2c4766d40d7f6346ed89d5d82fe75 and display the calorie value in index.html.erb file

Comment: @mohamed-ibrahim in create action after the food object is created

Comment: after object created it redirect to index anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new function to `Food` model to get you the Calorie:

```
class Food 

 def calorie
  response = HTTParty.get("http://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/#{self.name}?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_serving_size_unit%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=696d1ad4&appKey=aec2c4766d40d7f6346ed89d5d82fe75")
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)
 end
end
```

and then simply in your index.erb if you loop over `foods` collection you do the following:

```
<% @foods.each do |food| %>
   <%= food.name %>
   <%= food.calorie %>
<% end %>
```

but in that case performance will not be good, as you do remote access for each item each time you display data, so as calorie value is always the same for same food, then after its created you can do remote query and store the calorie to `calorie` attribute in your `Food` model

You can do the following:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_calorie

  private
  def set_calorie
    response = HTTParty.get("http://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/#{self.name}?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_serving_size_unit%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=696d1ad4&appKey=aec2c4766d40d7f6346ed89d5d82fe75")
    self.calorie = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

Comment: i had not defined the calorie value in Food model when i constructed so its giving error at food.calorie is it possible to add it now ?

Comment: i am new to ruby learning by tutorials also there are no helpful and easy tutorials :(

Comment: check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html
it will be `rails g migration add_calorie_to_foods calorie:float`

Comment: thanks that works i am able to get the calorie value of the food items but how to save calorie value in food instance of each food in the create method of foods_controller so that i dont  have to make api call again and again

Comment: i tried updating the calorie attribute of food item but in index.html.erb file nothing is getting displayed.Before applying your update i was trying like this see my index.html.erb at http://textuploader.com/5evtc and Food controller at http://textuploader.com/5evth and this was the response i was getting https://i.imgsafe.org/d9ada84b44.png now with your modification i am getting nothing in place of calorie values please help

Comment: because that should be applied for new data entered not old as well, and i can see you know where is the calorie value so i suggest change self.calorie to self.calorie = JSON.parse(response.body)["hits"][0]["fields"]["nf_calories"]

Comment: you can do simply: Food.sum(:calorie)

Comment: thanks a lot done with it.Thanks for your support you saved my day :)